# Codeigniter redirect with base_url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, codeigniter-url

I noticed that `anchor('controller/method')` produces a different result than a mere `<a href="controller/method">` in that `anchor()` adds the base_url:

`anchor('controller/method')`:

```
<a href="http://localhost/dts/controller/method">Link</a>
```

`<a>`:

```
<a href="controller/method">Link</a>
```

How do I achieve this same effect (anchor) in my controller? That is, adding the base_url in my redirects?

I'm asking because I have a form that calls another method `method2`, which has a `redirect('controller/method')`. But it redirects incorrectly to `controller/controller/method2`, then if the form is submitted again, redirects to `controller/controller/controller/method2` and so on.

That's why I'd like to know how to redirect to controller/method with the base_url pre-prended to it. `redirect( base_url() . 'controller/method' )` doesn't work.

index_page is set to:

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

base_url is set to:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/program/";
```

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

that's based on [this](http://jamieonsoftware.com/blog/entry/the-best-codeigniter-.htaccess) because the .htaccess provided by the CI manual doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost kemp, but no slashes needed.

```
redirect('controller/method');
```

What is your $config['base_url'] set to, because you are using the right functions and getting the wrong functionality.

Comment: I thought what the OP is getting was the expected behavior since he's providing a relative path.

Comment: dude i added the base_url info above

Comment: i updated the base_url and index_page values above, i incorrectly copied it before.

Comment: kemp: The slashes in the redirect() just screw with things, it has no effect on relative/absolute. Obay: How are you submitting your forms? if you are not using form_open('controller/method') it could be causing a problem.

Comment: im manually doing <form method="post" action="controller/method" />, haha i should try form_open()

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('controller/method');?>">

Comment: i used form_open('controller/method') and it works! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect('/controller/method');
```

Comment: this redirects to http://localhost/controller/method instead of http://localhost/program/controller/method

Comment: well, 'program' is the name of my web app

Comment: i updated the base_url and index_page values above, i incorrectly copied it before.

Comment: Well, setting the program name in `base_url` and using the syntax in my answer works fine for me: it redirects to `http://host/program_dir/controller/method`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `redirect( site_url('controller/method') );`

Don't forget to add the URL Helper class before using this `$this->load->helper('url');`.